# Kinect Audio PCM Values

Tags: c#, c++, audio, kinect, wav

Im using kinect to extract audio and classifie its features, but i have a question. On http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855698.aspx it says the audio.start method Opens an audio data stream (16-bit PCM format, sampled at 16 kHz) and starts capturing audio data streamed out of a sensor. The problem is that i dont know how pcm data is represented and i dont know if the method returns pcm true values or not. Because using the sdk examples i get values like 200, 56, 17 and i think audio values are more like -3*10^-5 .
So does anyone know how do i get the true PCM values? Or am i doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't expect any particular values. 16-bit PCM means it's a series of 16-bit integers, so -3*10<sup>-5</sup> (-0.00003) isn't representable.

I would guess it's encoded with 16-bit signed integers (like a WAV file) which have a range of -32768 to 32767. If you're being very quiet the values will probably be close to 0. If you make a lot of noise you will see some higher values too.

Check out [this diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aPcm.svg) (from Wikipedia's [article on PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation)) which shows a sine wave encoded as PCM using 4-bit unsigned integers, which have a range of 0 to 15.

See how that 4-bit sine wave oscillates around 7? That's it's *equilibrium*. If it was a signed 4-bit integer (which has a range of -8 to 7) it would have the same shape, but its equilibrium would be 0 - the values would be shifted by -8 so it would oscillate around 0.

You can measure the distance from the equilibrium to the highest or lowest points of the sine wave to get its *amplitude*, or broadly, it's volume (which is why if you're quiet you will mostly see values near 0 in your signed 16-bit data). This is probably the easiest sort of feature detection you can do. You can find plenty of good explanations on the web about this, for example http://scienceaid.co.uk/physics/waves/sound.html.

You could save it to a file and play it back with something like [Audacity](http://delog.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/playing-raw-pcm-audio-using-audacity/) if you're not sure. Fiddle with the input settings and you'll soon figure out the format.